# "The public type must be defined in its own file" but the file name and the class name is the same

Tags: java, drjava

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class josimarleewords {

    private static String[] tokenize(String str) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
        String[] arr = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
        int i = 0;
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            arr[i++] = tokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strs = tokenize("He said, That's not a good idea.");
        for (String s : strs)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the code above is in a file called `josimarleewords.java`, right?

Comment: Please edit your question to ask a question

Answer (score 2):

If your file is called Josimarleewords.java, then your class must be called Josimarleewords. Make sure you capitalize the first letter.

Comment: Worth noting, your class should be capitalised regardless because that is the convention.

Comment: OK Thnks You Guys i Just Fixed it Thank you soo much