# ChromeDriver and WebDriver for Selenium through TestNG results in 4 errors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I'm doing exactly what the website says but it results in 4 errors...

Comment: I'm not a Java Person, but are you missing any imports in your code?

Comment: He is. Use the magic keys Ctrl+Shift+o

Comment: And please rename the `Chrome.java` to `ChromeTest.java`

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are exactly **4** errors as follows:

- **Error**: *ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type*

  - **Solution**: You need to add the following import

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    ```
  - Here you can find a discussion on [chrome Webdriver can't be resolved to a type error eclipse and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897286/chrome-webdriver-cant-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-eclipse-and-java/48898627#48898627)
- **Error**: *Test cannot be resolved to a type*

  - **Solution**: You need to add the following import

    ```
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    //or
    import org.junit.Test;
    ```
- **Error**: *The public type ChromeTest must be defined in its own file*

  - **Solution**: Your filename is **Chrom.java** but your classname is **ChromeTest** where as both should have been similar. Change them as identical.
  - Here you can find a discussion on [“The public type must be defined in its own file” but the file name and the class name is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097029/the-public-type-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file-but-the-file-name-and-the-clas)
- **Error**: *WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type*

  - **Solution**: You need to add the following import

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    ```

### Best Practice

- You have to keep the filename (currently **Chrom.java**) and your classname (currently **ChromeTest**) identical as a mandatory measure.
- You need to mention the related *imports* whenever you are using any class. You can *Mouse Hover* over the error and choose the relevant import.
- You should either add the **testng** jars or the **junit** jars but not both of them.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, i didn't see any imports and class name was different from filename(As @yong mentioned in his comment).

Your Java file name should always reflect the public class defined within that file. Otherwise, you will get a compiler error.

Modify your code like this : 
(you had a typo, firstPackage)

```
package firstPackage;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

    @Test
    public void LaunchChrome_method(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: The website did not mention it. http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-chromedriver/

Comment: you had a typo. fisrtPackage -> firstPackage

Comment: Have you added selenium jar to the project.

Comment: junit was not in my package explorer list. I added it and then the error message was gone...