# WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type error using Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome through Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have issue in my selenium script might be issue in Eclipse i tryed all possible aspect with adding all JAR library with different version but i faild to run script expert please look where i stuck

```
package Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginbutton']")); 
        email.sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
        password.sendKeys("abcd123");
        login.click();
        System.out.println("Login Done with Click");    
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type

at Test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

This is my JAR library structure:

[image: This is my JAR library]

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
```

...implies that there were compilation issues in your program.

It is pretty evident from the snapshot you are using **Selenium v3.6.0** but I don't see any error as such in your code block. However you can follow the below mentioned steps to solve the issue:

- The *Package* name i.e. **`Test`** and the *Class* name i.e. **`Test`** needs to be different. You can't use the same name for the *package* and the *class*.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u202**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [ChromeDriver and WebDriver for Selenium through TestNG results in 4 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632698/chromedriver-and-webdriver-for-selenium-through-testng-results-in-4-errors/50646424#50646424)
- [chrome Webdriver can't be resolved to a type error eclipse and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897286/chrome-webdriver-cant-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-eclipse-and-java/48898627#48898627)
- [java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems : WebDriver/ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type error while executing selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111517/java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-problems-webdriver-chromedriver-cannot/50114884#50114884)

Comment: i Follow all update mention above script is still not execute gave  `Could not find or load main class DemoPkg.TestCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DemoPkg.Test` this error

Comment: @DebajanB, this error is caused by i changed my dependency as per above solution here i stuck with one another error, and most important if i solved this error might be previous error arrived again how can i accept your answer without solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need `selenium-java` on your classpath. The latest version at time of writing is 3.141.59.

[selenium-java 3.141.59](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/jar) ([direct download](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.jar))

[All versions](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.seleniumhq.selenium%20AND%20a:selenium-java&core=gav)

Comment: Tried this selenium-java in class path as well as in Module path but it's didn't work showing same error