# Not able to import "org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver" on MacOS

Tags: macos, selenium

I was writing a java program for selenium when tried to import `"org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver"` but it gives an error.
`"The import org.openqa cannot be resolved"` on my MacBook.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/shilpa/Documents/Selenium/Selenium Softwares/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Comment: What do you use to manage your dependencies ? Maven, gradle etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
The import org.openqa cannot be resolved
```

...implies that *ChromeDriver* wasn't resolved at **compiletime**.

There can be a lot many resons behind this error. A bit more about your *Test Environment* e.g. *JAR* files, *Maven* or *Gradle* and the binary versions would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. You can find a couple of relevant discussions in [ChromeDriver and WebDriver for Selenium through TestNG results in 4 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632698/chromedriver-and-webdriver-for-selenium-through-testng-results-in-4-errors/50646424#50646424) and [java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems : WebDriver/ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type error while executing selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897286/chrome-webdriver-cant-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-eclipse-and-java/48898627#48898627)

---

Morepver, as you are using *MacOS* you instead of using the *chromedriver.exe* from `chromedriver_win32.zip` you need to download, extract and use the **`chromedriver`** binary from **chromedriver_mac64** and change the `System.setProperty()` line as follows:

```
//without the extension (.exe)
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/shilpa/Documents/Selenium/Selenium Softwares/chromedriver");
```

Comment: I think that his problem is the `import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
`, it's not about the chrome driver

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel You are right. I have updated the answer.